# convert variation of letters to base letter in java

Tags: java

is there a function that gives me for any "variation" of a letter, (like 'à', 'ä', etc) the base letter('a')? Of course i know how to create a function using switch but i'd have to mind every single variation.

Answer (score 2):

you may utilise [Apache Common String Utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents%28java.lang.String%29)

for eg:

```
  String accentLetter1 = "ä";
  String accentLetter2 = "à";
  System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents(accentLetter1));
  System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents(accentLetter2));
```

displays

```
a
a
```

artifact is available in [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4)